# How to convert -0.00 to 0.00 in Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, decimal

How do I convert -0.00 to 0.00 in Python 3.4?  Following is an example.

```
a = Decimal(-0.00001)
a.quantize(Decimal('.01'),rounding=ROUND_HALF_UP)

Output: Decimal('-0.00')
```

Ideally, I would like to have 0.00

Comment: *The signed zeros can result from calculations that underflow. They keep the sign that would have resulted if the calculation had been carried out to greater precision. Since their magnitude is zero, both positive and negative zeros are treated as equal and their sign is informational.* Why do you want to have it `0.00`?

Comment: I'm going to pass that value upstream as a string that will ultimately be presented in the gui.  I don't want users to see -0.00.

Comment: Then Antii's approach is your best option.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
a = Decimal(-0.00001)
a = a.quantize(Decimal('.01'),rounding=ROUND_HALF_UP)
if a == 0:
    a = abs(a)
```

Comment: Decimal('-0.00') equals zero, but has negative sign only.

Comment: I'd use `abs(a)` or `a.copy_abs()` (for `-0.00` there is no difference between the two).

Comment: Is there a way to avoid the abs overhead?  If I'm looping a large data set, I'd rather not abs each item if I don't have to!

Comment: @Dowwie: If the `abs` overhead is costing you, you could create a single `Decimal('0.00')` object before your loop, and use that one value to replace all zeros (negative or positive) that you find. A bit like CPython's optimization for small integers. So: `if a == 0: a = my_special_zero`, or just `a = a or my_special_zero`

Answer (score 0):

Try getting the absolute value of the number using the `math.fabs()` function:

eg:

```
math.fabs(a)
```

Comment: This assumes that `a` is going to round to "exactly" zero, as opposed to a distinctly non-zero value.

Comment: the value after quantization IS exactly zero.

Comment: There is also [`Decimal.Context.abs()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/decimal.html#decimal.Context.abs) and [`Decimal.Context.copy_abs()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/decimal.html#decimal.Context.copy_abs) and [`Decimal.copy_abs()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/decimal.html#decimal.Decimal.copy_abs), or just the *built-in* [`abs()` function](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#abs). No need to import `math` here, we don't have a floating point value here.

Comment: @AnttiHaapala I mean, if `a` rounds to, say, `-0.03`, you don't want  set `a` to `0.03`.

Comment: That's a good point. How about putting a guard around the code, something like: `if(abs(a) == 0)`